# Spring 4, STS 3.7 tc server 3.1.1. how to enable insights for my existing web application?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite, tcserver, spring-insight

I am new to Spring framework even though i have been a java dev for quite some time. I am impressed by the spring insight application demos in you tube and want to use it in my application. How ever, when i try to create a new tc server using the instructions provided, for windows 8.1 64 bit

```
tcruntime-instance.bat create --template bio --template insight -i C:\workspaces\eclipses\sts\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.1.1.RELEASE\insight-instance http-insight-server-stsdeployed
```

When i try to add the folder created as the location of the new tc server with insight configured, using STS-> server view-> right click-> new-> server-> selected v3.0-3.1- && server-runtime env->add->browse="newly created server instance directory" it shows me below error.

```
 The Tomcat installation directory is not valid. It is missing expected file or folder tcruntime-ctl.sh.
```

any idea how to add a new server and run my application on it? or add spring insights to existing spring boot or spring web application thru maven or spring configuration?

Note: Even though im using STS, i would like to know how to use these instances with Eclipse or IntelliJ idea. Im on a windows 8.1 64 bit machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click "add" from your instructions, you are browsing to a new tc Server installation directory (the binaries you want to run) not the instance directory.  Once you select the installation directory of the version you wish to use, you will select next in the configuration and it will give you the option to "Create instance" or use an existing instance.  You will then select use an existing instance and point to your newly created instance directory.

Comment: I installed Pivotal tc Server Integration for Eclipse.where is it installation directory ?